# Wordpress Image LINK redirecting Http WWW

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have images on external site that I want to add on my post, but I want to make this by code:

```
<img src="www.domain.com/image.jpg" />
```

The problem is wordpress only accept with `http://` not `www` directly, If I put  without `http://` the wordpress rewrite it with my domain before the image address, so my image get a 404 error because it’s pointing to `http://mydomain.com/domain.com/image.jpg`

Any help to make it read images on my post point using only `www` and not needing `http` before the link?

Comment: You'll probably get better responses from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

This will always break:

```
<img src="www.domain.com/image.jpg" />
```

URLs need a scheme—like `http://`—connected to them to load resources.  So this is the only way it could work:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image.jpg" />
```

But perhaps you want the site to be accessible via `http://` and `https://` without having to worry about the image URLs?  Then this would work:

```
<img src="//www.domain.com/image.jpg" />
```

Using `//` without the `http:` tells the browser to access `www.domain.com/image.jpg` using whatever scheme was used to access the page to begin with.  So `//www.domain.com/image.jpg` can be used in pages that can potentially be loaded via `http://` and `https://` as is.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `http://`.  That is part of how HTML works, not just WordPress.